# SqlDataReader getting rows when no data

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sqldatareader

This is incredibly urgent, I need to present this application in 3 and a half hours.

My application checks against a data source to see if a value exists in the database and changes values depending on whether or not the value in question was found.
The problem is that I've run the sql query with the value in question in SSMS and no rows were returned, and yet, my DataReader says it has rows.

This means that my application is reporting inaccurately.
Here's my code:

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Testing;       Integrated Security=True;")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

    conn.Open()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If reader.HasRows Then
       Value = True
       AcctNumber = reader(1)
    End If

    reader.Close()
End Using
```

I've removed code that's not relevant to this post, but what you may want to know is:

Value is Boolean
AcctNumber is a String

As this is an application for work, I'd rather not include the SQL Query. The problem is the reader. If I comment out `Value = True`, I get the right info, but leaving that out will mean that in a case where Value should be True, it'll report inaccurately as well.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Full Source Code:

```
Case "Business"
    ' Change the number format to local because that's what it is in the db
    If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(NumberToCheck, 2) = "27" Then
        NumberToCheck = NumberToCheck.Replace(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(NumberToCheck, 2), "0")
    End If

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT a.TelNumber, c.AccountNumber " & _
            "FROM TelInfo a " & _
            "INNER JOIN Customers b ON a.CustID = b.pkguidId " & _
            "INNER JOIN Accounts c ON b.pkguidId = c.CustID " & _
            "WHERE a.TelNumber = '" & NumberToCheck & "'"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Testing; Persist Security Info=True; " & _
        "User Id=JoeSoap; Password=paoseoj;")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

        conn.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If reader.Read Then
            Value = True
            AcctNumber = reader(1)
         End If

        reader.Close()
    End Using
```

On the comments below made before 08/02/10 (mm/dd/yy):

`Value` is just a boolean that gets returned by the function to indicate that the searched telephone number (`NumberToCheck`) exists in the database.

So...

```
Private AcctNumber As String

Dim val As Boolean = False
val = CheckNumber("3235553469")
If val Then
    ' AcctNumber will have been set by CheckNumber
    Label1.Text = AcctNumber
End If
```

`val` will only be returned True if the NumberToCheck (in this example 3235553469) exists in the database.

Having copied the value of NumberToCheck into SSMS and testing the query there, I can verify that the query does work as expected.

No, I can't populate a DataSet because of the volume of information in the table (+/- 9.5m rows). Even with the 'WHERE' filter, the query is too heavy on resources and eventually ends in an `OutOfMemory Exception` which is why I went with a DataReader.

I'm going to try the `ExecuteScalar` option as suggested as an answer by Darryl now, will update with the results.

Comment: Can you show us the SQL?

Comment: I know the ConnectionString in the edit is different to the original. I had to change certain things for legal purposes... the information I'm working with is pretty sensitive.

Comment: The connection string is the least likely problem.

Comment: if value = true, can you check the AcctNumber too? Is it a valid account number coming from your database?

Comment: Oh, and are you sure that `"WHERE a.TelNumber = '" & NumberToCheck & "'"` works as expected? What's the value of `NumberToCheck` you're testing with?

Comment: Is there a problem perhaps with the difference between `reader.Read` (your code) and `reader.Read()` (what people are suggesting)?

Comment: Can you populate a DataSet using a DataAdapter and then step through the DataSet to see exactly what data is being returned?  Doing so might narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: @Kieren: there's no difference in VB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the immortal words of Homer Simpson... "DOH!!"

I just had a look on the database that my application searches for the telephone numbers and, I don't know how I could have missed it, but the value I'm searching for is actually there.

The problem is, therefore, not likely anything to do with my code, but rather the data...

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your `If` statement to

```
If reader.Read() Then
   Value = True
   AcctNumber = reader(1)  
End If
```

`HasRows` exhibits [strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasrows) in certain situations, so it's better to avoid it altogether.

Comment: +1 - it's basically breaking because the reader hasn't been moved to the first row.

Comment: Good suggestion, but no improvement

Comment: @Logan Make sure you're using correct `sql` and are issuing this statement against a correct DB -- there's nothing else that can go wrong here.

Comment: I just don't get it... the sql is correct because it works when I run it direct on the db, and I copied the connection string from an application that I know works.

Comment: @Logan I think it will be better if you posted full source code here.

Answer (score 1):

This does not solve the problem, but it may get you through your presentation.  Use "ExecuteScalar" which should work when you return a single value.

```
    AcctNumber = ""
    AcctNumber = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    If AcctNumber = "" Then
        Value = False
    Else
        Value = True
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure it's not a data problem, parameterize your SQL. Change the statement:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT a.TelNumber, c.AccountNumber " & _
        "FROM TelInfo a " & _
        "INNER JOIN Customers b ON a.CustID = b.pkguidId " & _
        "INNER JOIN Accounts c ON b.pkguidId = c.CustID " & _
        "WHERE a.TelNumber = @telNumber"
```

Then do this:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telNumber", NumberToCheck) ' <==== added line
```

**Edit**

I think we're looking in the wrong place. Add this just before `if reader.Read()`:

```
Value = false
AcctNumber = ""
```

This will make sure you're not having a variable-scope problem. (You *are* using `Option Strict On`, right?)

Comment: We might be having an overlapping-edit problem, your code still looks like `"'" & NumberToCheck & "'"`...?

Comment: Um... no, I didn't add that edit, my comment was on your post suggesting I obfuscate the code a little so that I can post...

Comment: OK, I've added the parameter with no improvement